# Multiple outputs on same SQL/PHP based chart

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I'm using a program that renders a chart using PHP/MySQL by retrieving data from a database.

It uses this structure:

```
$p->data_sql = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table ";
```

column 1 data will be used on the X axis and column 2 data will be used on the Y axis.

Pretty straight-forward, the problem though is that the above code will render one output only (say one line for a line chart).
My goal is to be able to render two outputs on the same chart. my second query is also simple:

```
SELECT column3, column2 FROM Table /*same table as for query 1*/
```

How can I put both queries into this structure and still let the application understand what goes on X axis and what goes on Y axis for both outputs?

I tried this but no success:

```
$p->data_sql = "select 
(SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table) as q1,
(SELECT column3, column2 FROM Table) as q2";
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
Actual query below:

```
$p->data_sql = "
SELECT concat(group_name, ' / ', side) groupid, sum(rs4) rs4t, 
   concat(group_name, ' / ', side) groupid, sum(rs3) rs3t 
FROM na_july16_resources_v2 
where group_name LIKE 'fighters%'
group by side";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a combined query to select 4 columns, one pair for each line to be drawn. Then have the receiving code use the columns it needs to draw line 1 or line 2

```
SELECT column1 x1, column2 y1
       column3 x2, column2 y2
FROM   myTable
```

The result set will have columns `x1, y1, x2, y2`

[**Live demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4c5f5/1)

Comment: Thanks @BeetleJuice but that did not work. The statement: $p->data_sql = "SELECT column1 x1, column2 y1, column3 x3, column2 y2 FROM myTable "; took only first two columns into account and just ignored the last two...

Comment: @Naim  You probably made a mistake either in the query or in the PHP code that fetches and process the result. The query itself is very basic. You can see it working for yourself; I've added a link to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Your query is correct and nothing is wrong with it. problem is that $p->data_sql ="select statement" does not consider anything beyond the first two variables. Ive added the full query in my question, maybe you'd notice something.